# How use the returned "buffer" of Electronjs function "getNativeWindowHandle()" in native functions?

Tags: windows, electron

I use the electronjs function `getNativeWindowHandle()` to find the HWND of electron main window.

I.e. one log was: `<Buffer@0x00000293A66F0450 ec 02 07 00 00 00 00 00>`

Converted to HEX: `ec02070000000000`

But the real HWND is: `459500`, obtained doing

`handleElectron.substring(0, 6).match(/.{1,2}/g)`, to have the three first couples of the string, then

`newhandle = handleElectron[2] + handleElectron[1] + handleElectron[0];` because the handle has the the fist two and the third two chars inverted.

Then I use `parseInt(handleElectron, 16) << 8) / 256` to obtain the decimal

Same result doing: `user32.FindWindowW(TEXT('Chrome_WidgetWin_1'), null);` (native function via node-ffi),

but I need to put it in a while loop because the `FindWindowW` sometimes gives 0.

Is there a cleaner and correct way to convert the result of `getNativeWindowHandle()` in HWND usable by `FindWindowW` or any other native functions?

Comment: Your machine is little-endian, like almost all of them.  So it is not 0xec02070000000000 but 0x0702ec and that's 459500 in decimal.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)! Any idea to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code returns the integer value you're looking for:

```js
const os = require("os")

function getNativeWindowHandle_Int(win) {
    let hbuf = win.getNativeWindowHandle()

    if (os.endianness() == "LE") {
        return hbuf.readInt32LE()
    }
    else {
        return hbuf.readInt32BE()
    }
}
```

It appears safe to assume that Windows is Little-Endian, but the code nevertheless checks the endianness using Node's `os.endianness()`. About reading only 32 bits, Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg64/interprocess-communication) says the following:

> When sharing a handle between 32-bit and 64-bit applications, only the lower 32 bits are significant, so it is safe to truncate the handle (when passing it from 64-bit to 32-bit) [..]

Call the function on a BrowserWindow as such:

```js
let myWin = new BrowserWindow()
console.log(getNativeWindowHandle_Int(myWin))
```

Comment: Super! It's what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wouldn't it be more robust to use unsigned integer (e.g. `hbuf.readUInt32LE()`)?

Comment: it shouldn't make a difference, as the value is never higher than `2^31-1`

Answer (score 1):

Add an answer for Mac.

```
// ts
const handle = window.getNativeWindowHandle();
testNativeWindow(handle);

// mm
auto buffer = info[0].As<Napi::Buffer<uint8_t>>();
void **handle = reinterpret_cast<void **>(buffer);
NSView* electronView = (__bridge NSView *)*handle;
```

Comment: NSView* nsView = *reinterpret_cast<NSView**>(buffer.Data());